# I deleted too many system apps but I made backup.. My tablet stuck on android logo

Tags: applications, backup, system

A virus similar to **monkey test** that I almost solved the problem with *Titanium Backup* app until I **deleted too many system apps.** Now my tablet **stuck on android logo**. However I backed up all apps with Titanium and copied it to my computer.

Please tell me there is hope. I almost solve three month problem by following steps with Titanium but I overdone it. I hope there is still a solution  with the backup I made. I really don't care about the data my problem always was that I never found a ROM for my device but I am no expert. It could be there and I did't not see it.

The virus was similar to the monkey test but it wasn't the same. That's why it was hard to follow steps latterly. Whatever it takes to get my device back it is so important for me. I will right the build number for the tab and upload all apps images and a video  for its settings ,model number and virus apps, only images was after deleting obvious virus apps. I really appreciate any help.

Build number: rk_30 android 4.1.1 sdk v1.00.00 bsmart bs101 v1.0 20130316.

[**Video showing all info**][2]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC-Km8pdOf8

i spent the past time trying to learn more about adb ,and i found this video when searching it could be the solution for my problem and i hope it is helpful video for others. i don't want to make the same mistake twice so i'm waiting for your advice before continue in these steps, also i put an image after i did the first step only to make my computer reed my tab on adb

[image: deleted system apps]

Comment: Which Android device is it? It can't be helped now. You must find and flash the stock ROM.

Comment: it is bsmart 10.1" bs101 can you help me find any rom for it's cpu is cortex a7 dual core 1.3 ram 1g resolution 1280*800 16g nand flash ?

Answer (score 1):

If you backed up the apps you removed, you should be able to just adb push them back to the device OR copy/paste to the system app directory if that's available from Windows/Linux (etc) file explorer. Assuming all you did was delete some apk's.

If you didn't and you can find a stock rom, you might be able to do the same but instead getting the apk's from the rom.

Its possible that doing so may not work (depending on how the rom is set up and what you have available) and that you need to (re-)flash a rom (even just a dirty flash of the same rom or newer should get you back in).

But what you should have done was a full backup via adb, made sure there was a rom available for flashing, or installed a recovery and made a full backup before messing around in the system section. BACKUP backup backup!

A more direct answer may be obtained from the device thread on xda website where multiple people likely know the device well enough to get you through it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably stuck on the logo because, you could've deleted a system app that was named com.android.bluetooth-20151217-190009 which is a PROPERTIES file. You might want to bring it in to the Google Store. This is why you do not mess with system apps! It brings a lot of trouble to your phone.
Now, if you deleted the apps because you wanted storage, That is not a good idea, because your phone may overflow with downloaded with apps and games, which is not healthy for your device. Bringing it to the Google Store, they may fix your problem.

Comment: thank you it was all about deleting the virus without enough exeperties, what is right command to paste it in cmd to do solve the problem